electrical - 12v switch malfunction?
The car is a 1998 Galaxy 1.9 tdi. Swapped an old aftermarket stereo (working) for more recent one. the new one doesn't turn on and now neither the old one!
With a multimeter on the car harness, I get 12v from yellow constant to black ground, 0v from red switch to black with or without the key turned, and i get 12v from yellow to red. I don't want to tear down the console much more to chase that red. any simple solution to this? thanks in advance

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you check your fuses?

Thanks and thank you for the imput. This make/model has 2 fuses for the radio - position 19 and 25(switch) was busted. I got a 20A spare fuse that went to the switch 25 and since the radio has an 10A built in im good with it.
Now the key turn and the radio goes hello! and you remove the key and bye bye. All good in the neighborhood

If you have the answer, post it as such.

This make/model has 2 fuses for the radio - position 19 and 25(switch) was busted. I got a 20A spare fuse that went to the switch 25 and since the radio has an 10A built in im good with it.
It works as it should now. Thanks
